# how to implement GestureRecognizers LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout?

Tags: uicollectionview, ios8.2

I'm using a
[LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout](https://github.com/lukescott/LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout) library.
I had implement the required methods of the delegate, but one of methods called **collectionView:canMoveItemAtIndexPath:** is not called.

and i want to know how gesture methods are being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this library is deprecated. You can use [DraggableCollectionView](https://github.com/lukescott/DraggableCollectionView)

which is written by the same developer/team and easy to implement.
It serves the same purpose.

Make sure you have added draggable key of type boolean to YES in run time attributes of collection view.
[image]

and you have added DraggableView delegate to your interface for example.[image]

Comment: I had downloaded the library, but also the same problem delegate methods are no called.

Comment: @mustafa i hope you have make draggable to YES. See my Edit